# How to map a table column to two entity properties?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, mapping

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677981/creating-a-view-of-an-entity) case, i'm trying to map a table column **IsActive** to two different entity property. is there any way to do this?

Comment: How are you creating the entity model? Designer, manually or code first?

Comment: @Richard:I create it using designer, but manipulations are manually.

Comment: What happens if you add two properties to the conceptual (CSDL) with two mappings (MSL) to the same underlying property? (This will require, AIUI, editing the XML directly.)

Comment: i did, but "3021: Each of the following columns in table Receipts is mapped to multiple conceptual side properties:
Receipts.IsDeleted is mapped to <Receipts.IsDeleted, Receipts.IsDel>"

Comment: I think you have your answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. Each column must be mapped only once because otherwise it would lead to inconsistencies. For example if you would set different value to each property which one should be saved? Also having two properties exposing same field doesn't make sense.

Comment: It does make sense if you would like to use the same varchar(max) column for text or json and depending on what property you use, you either work with json or text. e.g. properties: ConfigValueJson ValueJson and string ValueText. You can use the same column to store two different data structures which are text. Entity framework could just overwrite one change if you change both in the same context, or do a comparison and merge changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two properties in the same Entity mapped to the same column.

But there are techniques called "Table Splitting" and "Entity Splitting"
http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/table-splitting-in-code-first-entity-framework.aspx
and http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Entity-Splitting-in-Code-First-Entity-Framework.aspx

So you can have two different Entities mapped to the same table.

Comment: The links are no longer valid.