# C# Fluent API Map two properties to same column

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, fluent, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

My problem is actually quite straight forward:

This is the MySQL table *"ClubCategory"*. As you can see it links a club to a category.

```
+------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CategoryId | int  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ClubId     | int  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The problem is as follows: My backing C# class has to implement an Interface that specifies an additional property named `OtherId` where `OtherId` is just an alias for `CategoryId`.

The class looks as follows

```csharp
public class ClubCategory : IClubFilterLinker
{
    private int _categoryId;

    public int ClubId { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId
    {
        get => _categoryId;
        set => _categoryId = value;
    }

    public int OtherId
    {
        get => _categoryId;
        set => _categoryId = value;
    }
}
```

I basically need to be able to use either `ClubCategory.CategoryId` or `ClubCategory.OtherId` to access the same database column `CategoryId`.

The Fluent API mapping I tried looks like this:

```csharp
modelBuilder.Entity<ClubCategory>()
    .Property(nameof(_categoryId))
    .HasColumnName("CategoryId")
    .HasColumnType("INT")
    .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<ClubCategory>()
    .Property(cc => cc.CategoryId)
    .HasField(nameof(_categoryId))
    .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);

modelBuilder.Entity<ClubCategory>()
    .Property(cc => cc.OtherId)
    .HasField(nameof(_categoryId))
    .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

However the resulting generated MySQL query when accessing an instance of this class

```sql
SELECT `c`.`ClubId`, `c`.`CategoryId`, `c`.`OtherId`, `c`.`CategoryId`
FROM `club2category` AS `c`
```

is obviously completely broken. Not only does it specify `CategoryId` twice but it also tries to access a fictional column named `OtherId` that doesn't exist in the database :|

So what do I need to change in Fluent API to successfully map both properties to the same MySQL column?
Or is it possible at all? Any help would be hugely appreciated :)

Comment: What's the problem with just not mapping `OtherId` at all? Do you need to be able to use both in a query?

Comment: @TimRogers Exactly. We need to be able to use both properties in queries. The interface will be occasionally used in some other code to generate queries and is implemented by multiple other linking tables where the same problem occurs :)

Comment: Not possible then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678972/how-to-map-a-table-column-to-two-entity-properties

Comment: @TimRogers I actually managed to find a  workaround. So in my use case it actually *is* possible :D

Comment: That's good news. I've reopened this one. Feel free to answer your own question, then we can mark the other question a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @TimRogers Alright done. I'll have to wait 2 days though until I can accept my answer

Comment: Running into this today but instead of the same column twice it actually makes up a new one, in this case like ClubCategory_CategoryId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through all the intellisense suggestions of the `PropertyBuilder` one method caught my attention: `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()`.

From the documentation:

> Configures a property to have a value generated when saving a new or existing entity.

Adding this to the `PropertyBuilder` chain seems to tell the Entity Framework that the value is automatically generated by the database upon saving. Therefore EF excludes this property from it's query during insert or update. Essentially allowing you to map multiple of these *"readonly"* properties to the same database column and use them in your queries which is exactly what I asked for in my question. This also allows me to remove the private backing field.

My `ClubCategory` class now looks like this:

```csharp
public class ClubCategory : IClubFilterLinker
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public int OtherId { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the corresponding Fluent API mapping:

```csharp
modelBuilder.Entity<ClubCategory>()
    .Property(cc => cc.CategoryId)
    .HasColumnName("CategoryId")
    .HasColumnType("INT")
    .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<ClubCategory>()
    .Property(cc => cc.OtherId)
    .HasColumnName("CategoryId")
    .HasColumnType("INT")
    // Prevent EF from using this property in insert / update statements.
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```