# EF Core Property/Column Sharing

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, .net-7.0, ef-fluent-api

## Original Question

I have the following entity I’m trying to get to work with EF Core/NET7, where two properties map to the same column. This way either property could be used in various interfaces without breaking old code.

Any way to make this work in EF Core?

```
public class AppUser 
{
  public int Id { get; internal set; }
  public string Name { get => UserName; set => UserName = value; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
}
. . .
var item = context.Set<AppUser>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == “admin”).ToList();
. . .
builder.Property(x => x.UserName)
  .HasColumnName(“UserName”);
builder.Ignore(x => x.Name);
// or
builder.Property(x => x.Name)
  .HasColumnName(“UserName”)
  .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

Or is there a way of making the Name property project to UserName, similar to how AutoMapper projections map DTO fields with IQueryable extensions?

## Edit

The `AppUser` class is actually derived from `IdentityUser<int>`, so the idea is to use the class with both the ASP.NET Core Identity framework AND internal classes that require a `INameEntity` type. Updated definitions are below.

Also, I tried using `builder.Property(u => u.Name).HasColumnName("UserName").ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676906/c-sharp-fluent-api-map-two-properties-to-same-column), but it throws the exception `Invalid column name 'UserName1'.`

If it helps, I'm using NET7.

#### Entity Definitions

```
public interface INameEntity
{
  int Id { get; }
  string Name { get; }
}

public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>, IEquatable<AppUser>, INameEntity
{
  public int Id { get; internal set; }
  public string Name { get => UserName; set => UserName = value; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

#### EF Core Fluent API Definition

```
public class AppUserConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AppUser>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AppUser> builder)
  {
    . . .
    builder.Property(u => u.UserName)
      .HasColumnName(“UserName”)
      .HasMaxLength(ModelConfig.MaxUserNameLen)
      .IsRequired();

    builder.Ignore(u => u.Name);
    . . .
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to generate queries based on both properties? Or can you mark them as `[Obsolete, NotMapped]`?

Comment: Or tell EF Core the property is database generated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676906/c-sharp-fluent-api-map-two-properties-to-same-column

Comment: Please add more details. Which interfaces, how do you plan to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this my extension [EFCoreLinqExtensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77148925/10646316) for replacing `AppUser.Name` property to `AppUser.UserName` in LINQ query.

Usage is simple:

```cs
public class AppDbContext: DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        // We add AppUser.Name property replacement to use AppUser.UserName.
        optionsBuilder.UseMemberReplacement((AppUser u) => u.Name,
            u => u.UserName);
    }
}
```

Extension should automatically correct LINQ query to be translatable.

Comment: Perfect! This does exactly what I'm looking for.